# Trouble with filter in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have been using `dplyr` for a while now and came across some unexpected behavior. I have a selected a column `ID` from a tibble of the following form:

```
ID
<chr>
123
123
123
123
456
456
456
789
789
```

I wanted to select by "123" so I did the following:

```
dplyr::filter(ID == "123")
```

and get `0 rows`. I should note that this is the build from github. Has anyone run across a similar issue? Is there additional formatting I can apply to the column so the filter works?

Comment: Where is the dataset object in the code?  `df1 %>% filter(ID == "123")`  Also, check whether you have leading/lagging spaces i.e. `df1 %>% filter(trimws(ID)=="123")`

Comment: @akrun It was the white space `trimws()` did the trick. Thanks!